# How do I resolve this phonegap iOS build error?

Tags: ios, cordova

> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't
>   include the aps-environment entitlement.

Been digging around for hours and can't find an explanation of how to resolve this so I can build from command line. I know of no provisioning file that's named this way. It almost seems like some kind of default.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wants to run the app for development, without push notifications,Turn off push notifications from capabilities in Targets in Xcode else you have to on push notification in certificate.

Comment: did you try this ?